# I can't see skins in 1.10.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

All the skins I see are the steve and alex models, including my own skin. I've tried resetting my laptop, re-logging in, but nothing works. What do I do? Even my skin model is broken.
[image]

Comment: Does playing on another server (or in single player) fix this? (If yes, it's Mineplex's problem due to a bug in their Bungiecord system (most likely caused by faulty version protocol switching or that it's working correctly, but serving you a newer version of Minecraft's protocols that 1.10.2 cannot understand). If no, it's Mojang's servers or your internet having issues).

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do anything. Just wait. I'm sure, almost all of the minecraft players have experienced this/

Comment: So you're saying it's a error of the multiplayer server?

Comment: yes, it is an error.